# distinguish between not found element and the one with index -1 in javascript array

Tags: javascript

Common way to find the element in an array is to use indexOf() method of Array. The issue appears when there is an element with negative index, i.e. -1. Check this scenario:

```
var arr = [];
arr[-1] = '2';

console.log(arr.indexOf('2')); // -1
console.log(arr.indexOf('unknown')); //-1
```

Basically, I could have implemented a workaround to distinguish between non existing element and the one with index -1 (repeat similar logic as in indexOf and return NaN when element could not be found), but just curious - isn't there existing implementation addressing the issue above?

Comment: Only non-negative numeric indexes are considered by code that expects array-like behavior from an object. For example, setting the `-1` element of your array will not increase the `length` property, because the array doesn't think that the property is really part of the "array" personality of the object.

Comment: Why would you need to use negative indices? `arr[-100] = 2; arr.indexOf(2) === -1;//true`

Comment: as asked before,why the hell would you use negative indexes anyway?

Comment: As for need for negative indexes - it depends on particular scenario, for instance to keep a map of surface where negative indexes correspond to underground values, or in current scenario the array represents id of drivers and > 0 is normal id, whereas 0 means transient, -1 unknown,  -6 pending identification etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays can't have negative indices. When you do `arr[-1] = '2'` you're setting the "-1" property of the array object instead.

When you do `arr.indexOf('2');` it doesn't actually find anything and therefore returns -1 to signify "element not found", not "found at index -1". Proof:

```
var arr = [];
arr[-2] = '2';

console.log(arr.indexOf('2')); // -1
```